# Which grows asymptotically faster, $\log \sqrt{n}$ or $4 \log n$?

Tags: asymptotics

I have been looking at the question as to which grows faster asymptotically; $\log \sqrt n$ or $4 \log n$.  I have applied L'Hopitals rule and ended up with 1/8.  This would imply that they grow at same rate.

Graphically $4 \log n$ is always above $\log \sqrt n$.  Also from a perspective that $4 \log n$ is $\log n^4$ would imply intuitively that growth of $4 \log n$ is faster asymptotically

There appear to be contradictions.

Comment: Also, 1/2 logn vs 4 logn they would appear to be same growth rate

Answer (score 2):

The [asymptotic growth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) of
$4 \log n$ is referred to as $\Theta(\log n)$.  You will have to look at
the definition of asymptotic growth to see why that is the case, but
*intuitively*, it is the growth of a function when we discard constant
factors and only look at the function "in the limit".

You have found out that the difference between the two functions "is
1/8", which makes sense, and which would put these two functions in the
same "growth class".

When it comes to $\Theta\left(\log ( \sqrt n ) \right)$, it is, as you
likely have found out
$$\Theta\left(\log ( n^{1/2} ) \right) = \Theta\left( \frac{1}{2}\log n
\right) = \Theta\left(\log n \right).$$

Comment: I replaced $O(\cdot)$ with $\Theta(\cdot)$ since $f(n),g(n)=O(h(n))$ does not tell us anything about whether $f(n) = \Omega(g(n))$ and/or $f(n)=O(g(n))$.